# Merge json files, overwriting

Tags: php, json, merge

I have several json files, all of them with the same structure, each of them for a different year:

```
  {"AEK":{"country":"Greece","shtv":"VEK"} ,
   "BER":{"country":"Germany","shtv":"BKE"} ,
   "CAR":{"country":"Italy","shtv":"CRA"}}

  {"AEK":{"country":"Greece","shtv":"MOR"} ,
   "DAR":{"country":"Turkey","shtv":"DDR"}}

  {"AEK":{"country":"Greece","shtv":"MIL"} ,
   "BER":{"country":"Germany","shtv":"BKE"} ,
   "CAR":{"country":"Italy","shtv":"KUN"}}
```

They are called data_2014.json, data_2015.json and data_2016.json.

The final json I would like to have, using PHP, is alldata.json like this:

```
  {"AEK":{"country":"Greece","shtv":"MIL"} ,
   "BER":{"country":"Germany","shtv":"BKE"} ,
   "CAR":{"country":"Italy","shtv":"KUN"},
   "DAR":{"country":"Turkey","shtv":"DDR"}}
```

I mean: for the elements that are repeated, get the latest information available (i.e., for AEK element, get the property "shtv"="MIL", which was the one from data_2016.json. For the elements that are not repeated, just get the info available.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: This is not a question or even a problem statement...it's just a dump of some requirements. We are not a free do-my-research or write-my-code site. Normally you're expected to at least try something for yourself, especially as this is not a very unusual task. People may answer you in any case, but you'll find that your post is also likely to attract downvotes, and less answers than it might otherwise have done. People are giving their free time to help you, please respect that by spending some of your own time first to look into the problem before posting a question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to convert your JSON into array using [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and then merge all json array using [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) and then encode again using [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to get all json into one.

```
$json1 = '{"AEK":{"country":"Greece","shtv":"VEK"} ,
"BER":{"country":"Germany","shtv":"BKE"} ,
"CAR":{"country":"Italy","shtv":"CRA"}}';

$json2 = '{"AEK":{"country":"Greece","shtv":"MOR"} ,
"DAR":{"country":"Turkey","shtv":"DDR"}}';

$json3 = '{"AEK":{"country":"Greece","shtv":"MIL"} ,
"BER":{"country":"Germany","shtv":"BKE"} ,
"CAR":{"country":"Italy","shtv":"KUN"}}';

$arr1 = json_decode($json1,true);
$arr2 = json_decode($json2,true);
$arr3 = json_decode($json3,true);

$finalArr = array_merge($arr1,$arr2,$arr3);

$final_json = json_encode($finalArr);

echo $final_json;
```

Answer (score 0):

For this first, you have to decode the json value by using json_decode().

```
$var1= '{"AEK":{"country":"Greece","shtv":"VEK"} ,
"BER":{"country":"Germany","shtv":"BKE"} ,
"CAR":{"country":"Italy","shtv":"CRA"}}';

$var2= '{"AEK":{"country":"Greece","shtv":"MOR"} ,
"DAR":{"country":"Turkey","shtv":"DDR"}}';

$var3= '{"AEK":{"country":"Greece","shtv":"MIL"} ,
"BER":{"country":"Germany","shtv":"BKE"} ,
"CAR":{"country":"Italy","shtv":"KUN"}}';
```

And also pass true with json_decode($var, TRUE) because **TRUE**, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

```
$array1= json_decode($var1,true);
$array2= json_decode($var2,true);
$array3 =json_decode($var3,true);
```

Then you have array_merge() of these three array value and you will get you desired output.

$result = json_encode(array_merge($array1,$array2,$array3));

$result returns

```
{"AEK":{"country":"Greece","shtv":"MIL"},
 "BER":{"country":"Germany","shtv":"BKE"},
  "CAR":{"country":"Italy","shtv":"KUN"},
  "DAR":{"country":"Turkey","shtv":"DDR"}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$json1_str = file_get_contents('data_2014.json');
$json2_str = file_get_contents('data_2015.json');
$json3_str = file_get_contents('data_2016.json');

$json1_array = json_decode($json1_str, true);
$json2_array = json_decode($json2_str, true);
$json3_array = json_decode($json3_str, true);

$array = array_merge($json1_array, $json2_array, $json3_array);
$final_output=json_encode($array);
```